# R: Efficiently filter numeric vector by selecting multiple subregions

Tags: r, select, vector

I have a relatively large numeric vector `x`, and I'm only interested in values that are found within `n` subregions specified by `lower` and `upper` bounds (inclusive). What is the most efficient (most important), and concise (less important as long as code is readable) method of accomplishing this? I need the output to be a vector of logical (or integer) values so that I can index another vector with the selected regions.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
x <- 1:20
lower <- c(0.8, 3.9,  9, 12, 19)
upper <- c(2.1, 6.1, 13, 17, 19)
```

The output should be:

```
out <- c(TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
         TRUE,  TRUE, TRUE,  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

I have a solution but it seems a bit hacky to me and I have no idea if it's efficient:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

out.list <- map2(lower, upper, ~ between(x, .x, .y))
out.mat <- do.call(rbind, out.list)
out.vec <- apply(out.mat, 2, any)

# Check output
all(out.vec == out)
[1] TRUE
```

Although `x` is not expected to be much larger than a million elements, I will need to repeat the process for many different values of x.

**Edit:** Updated example with floating point and overlapping bounds.

**Update:** I think this question is more concise and general than the linked one. I would have selected the deleted `data.table` answer instead of the selected answer in the linked question (which had a preference for dplyr/tidyr).

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

lower <- runif(100, 0.5, 8.5)
upper <- runif(100, 0, 1)
x <- runif(1e5, 1, 10)

microbenchmark(inrange = inrange(x, lower, upper),
               sapply = sapply(x,function(v){ any(v >= lower & v <= upper) })) 

   expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq      max neval
inrange   5.757293   5.991459   6.527294   6.10907   6.417622  10.0425   100
 sapply 280.412724 290.914073 300.813885 295.15648 300.568322 356.7478   100
```

Comment: Just saw this post once I started to look up the `inrange` function.

Comment: We can close this as a dupe if the linked answer is ok

Comment: @docendodiscimus No problem, but I prefer the `inrange()` solution that you had posted. The linked question had a stated preference for dplyr/tidyr.

Answer (score 1):

What about this ?

```
out <- sapply(x,function(v){ any(v >= lower & v <= upper) })

> out 
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```